# For a web application in Python running in a web server with WSGI, how to have one single WSGI Worker performing a task?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, worker

My web application with Python 3.9 and Flask is running in a web server with WSGI.
As more users connect to the web server, more workers are started by WSGI, but there are some tasks that must be performed by one single WSGI worker, rather than all Workers at the same time.

Among such tasks to be performed by one single worker are:

1. delete obsolete files in the disk
2. copy some data from a file to REDIS
3. delete specific lines in various TXT and LOG files

If all workers do such tasks, then a mess starts.
How to have one single worker doing it, rather than all workers?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into implementing an asynchronous task queue; something like [celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) would work to do this, you can define the frequency at which tasks run.